# COM: Getting GUID of coclass object using pointer to interface it implements

Tags: c++, com

Having pointer to COM interface that are implemented by some concrete component class object is it possible to get a GUID of the underlying object that implements this interface (CLSID)?

#### Update 1

More generally, I have a function like `SetFont(ICanvasFont* font)` and I need a way to determine if the underlying object that implements the `ICanvasFont` interface is of a certain class (say `MCanvasFont`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IUnknown::QueryInterface` on this interface pointer to obtain one of the following: `IPersist`, `IPersistStream`, `IPersistStreamInit` or other `IPersist*` interfaces. If you are lucky to get one, then `GetClassID` method will get you the `CLSID` class identifier (alternate option is `IProvideClassInfo` and `IProvideClassInfo::GetClassInfo`).

Note that this kind of information does not have to exist. An interface pointer can be valid without having `CLSID` on the class implementing it.

UPD. If the main goal is to recognize your own implementation on the provided interface ("Is the provided `ICanvasFont` the instance of my own `MCanvasFont` class, or it is something different?"), then the easiest yet efficient way is to implement some extra private interface on the class. If your querying it succeeds, then you recognize the instance. Provided no marshaling takes place, you can possibly even `static_cast` back to original C++ pointer.