# List of all categories of filters and hardware devices under Windows

Tags: c++, windows, filter, categories, directshow

When I run (in C++)
`CoCreateInstance (CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum [...])`
and then
`CreateClassEnumerator (CLSID_ActiveMovieCategories [...]),`
I get 28 categories. But I know there are more categories than that, some of which are installed on my system, for example:

```
KSCATEGORY_BDA_NETWORK_PROVIDER, "BDA network provider"    {71985F4B-1CA1-11D3-9CC8-00C04F7971E0}
CLSID_VideoEffects1Category,     "Video effect (1 input)"  {CC7BFB42-F175-11D1-A392-00E0291F3959}
CLSID_MediaEncoderCategory,      "EncAPI encoder"          {7D22E920-5CA9-4787-8C2B-A6779BD11781}
```

whose members I can list with the likes of
`CreateClassEnumerator (CLSID_VideoEffects1Category [...]).`
Is there a way to list ALL categories of filters and hardware devices on a system, including those like video effects category that are not mapped to any DirectShow category?

Comment: "I **know** there are more categories..." - how do you know? Enumerate them the way you know this.

Comment: You have full enumeration already

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate categories as described in [DirectShow Filter Meta-Category](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/filter-categories#directshow-filter-meta-category) section:

> This meta-category contains a list of filter categories. If a filter category does not appear within this list, the Filter Mapper ignores the category, which means the filter is not available for Intelligent Connect.
>
> **To enumerate the list of filter categories**, call `ICreateDevEnum::CreateClassEnumerator` with the value `CLSID_ActiveMovieCategories`. The monikers returned by this method support the following properties.

This enumerates categories created by third parties as well.

As mentioned in the [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65256026/868014) source code of [GraphStudioNext](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next):

[image]

It is generally not recommended, but you can also read the categories from registry, under `HKCR\CLSID\<GUID of CLSID_ActiveMovieCategories>\Instance` key.

Comment: Your question does not make sense in the part of "all categories". There are no all categories in first place. The part "If a third party application created a custom category and installed " is covered by the documented API in particular, as covered by the body of the answer above.

Comment: The fact that enumeration API takes additional category GUIDs does not mean they are a part of any enumeration. Specifically those categories you mention are now clearly marked as deprecated part of API and are removed from Windows SDK. DirectShow exposes them to keep runtime compatibility with legacy applications (which use DES). There does not have to be a method defined to list them.

Comment: GUIDs that are accepted by the API and possibly showing some items are of these two sorts: `1` explicitly handled by the API runtime to expose items with specially defined meaning (DES case) `2` unintentionally made available because of common surface with other APIs, and, this way, picking up non-DirectShow items via DirectShow API. In both cases the categories itself are not expected to be inlcuded into some sort of comprehensive registry.

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed more categories on the system then the enumerator reports

What I do in my code is to merge the results from the enumerator with a fixed table of all known categories

on my test system i find devices for 47 categories, of which 23 categories are found via my guid table embedded into the application.